# How to make grouping in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am generating *pdf* with *JasperReports* with XML as a data source.

I have table like 
[image]

and XML is as below:

```
<multiplerecord type="PAF_DETAILS">
    <record PAFNO="PAF121" MINCOMM="5" INVOICENO="BILL000000121" TYPE="Exclusive" CATEGORY="Category I" SLABNO="Slab 1"/>
    <record PAFNO="PAF122" MINCOMM="5" INVOICENO="BILL000000122" TYPE="Exclusive" CATEGORY="Category I" SLABNO="Slab 1"/>
    <record PAFNO="PAF123" MINCOMM="5" INVOICENO="BILL000000123" TYPE="Exclusive" CATEGORY="Category I" SLABNO="Slab 1"/>
    <record PAFNO="PAF124" MINCOMM="5" INVOICENO="BILL000000124" TYPE="Exclusive" CATEGORY="Category I" SLABNO="Slab 1"/>
    <record PAFNO="PAF125" MINCOMM="5" INVOICENO="BILL000000125" TYPE="Exclusive" CATEGORY="Category I" SLABNO="Slab 1"/>
    <record PAFNO="PAF124" MINCOMM="5" INVOICENO="BILL000000124" TYPE="Exclusive" CATEGORY="Category I" SLABNO="Slab 2"/>
    <record PAFNO="PAF122" MINCOMM="5" INVOICENO="BILL000000122" TYPE="Exclusive" CATEGORY="Category I" SLABNO="Slab 2"/>
    <record PAFNO="PAF123" MINCOMM="5" INVOICENO="BILL000000123" TYPE="Exclusive" CATEGORY="Category I" SLABNO="Slab 2"/>
    <record PAFNO="PAF126" MINCOMM="5" INVOICENO="BILL000000126" TYPE="Non - Exclusive" CATEGORY="Category I" SLABNO="Slab 1"/>
    <record PAFNO="PAF127" MINCOMM="5" INVOICENO="BILL000000127" TYPE="Non - Exclusive" CATEGORY="Category I" SLABNO="Slab 1"/>
    <record PAFNO="PAF128" MINCOMM="5" INVOICENO="BILL000000128" TYPE="Non - Exclusive" CATEGORY="Category I" SLABNO="Slab 1"/>
  </multiplerecord>
```

How this is achieve in *JasperReports* with *iReport 4.5.1*.
I am new to JR.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can read [this faq at jasperforge.org](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#groups)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<group name="Type">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{TYPE}]]></groupExpression>
</group>
```

The group can contain group header, group footer ... and you can use multiple groups in JasperReport. Make sure that the data are properly  sorted, sorting should correspond with defined groups. Sorting in your example seems ok already. You can define group easily in iReport designer.